# Comparing Two Strings producing a numeric delta

Tags: string, comparison

Does anyone know of a simple way to compare two strings together to generate the "amount of difference" between the two? (in a numeric value) I have been crawling google with little luck on this. And after doing some coding it's not as simple as I had thought. Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about the "Edit Distance"? Do a search on "Levenshtein Distance", on SO or Google. I use the version posted on [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/05/590814.aspx)

Comment: Upmod for being faster than me.  :)

Comment: that's one of the great things about SO -- I saw an earlier post on the topic, and it was immediately useful for me. Glad I could return the favor!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: By 10 seconds.  That's actually a lot considering the Levenshtein distance between what we each typed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) distances. One calculates edit distance (insert, delete, modify) and the other bit flips.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to very clearly define "amount of difference".  There's a lot of wiggle room in there.

For example, the old C/C++ function `strcmp()` function compared character by character and returned the difference the first time they didn't match.

On the other hand, the diff program provides a comprehensive list of differences between two files (which, in once sense, are also strings).  How would you quantify that?